# Why PASSWORD_HASHERS is a list rather than a string in Django?

Tags: django

At a time we can use only one password hashing algorithm,then what is the purpose of proving a list of password hashing algorithms in django settings file?

Comment: Django releases security updates that change the default algorithm or number of iterations used. When someone logs in their password will be re-hashed if it is using an old algorithm or number of iterations. To support users with potentially very old passwords this setting lists the old algorithms used/supported so that those passwords can be validated and re-hashed

Answer (score 0):

I hope the [doc-(*How Django stores passwords*)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords) itself self-explanatory,

> Django chooses the algorithm to use by consulting the `PASSWORD_HASHERS`
> setting. This is a list of hashing algorithm classes that this Django
> installation supports. The first entry in this list (that is,
> `settings.PASSWORD_HASHERS[0]`) will be used to store passwords, and all
> the other entries are valid hashers that can be used to check existing
> passwords. This means that if you want to use a different algorithm,
> you’ll need to modify `PASSWORD_HASHERS` to list your preferred
> algorithm first in the list.